# How to transform one Poisson distributed random variable to another with a different mean?

Tags: probability, distributions

Since the simple affine transformation does not preserve Poisson distribution, I'm wondering if there is any trick to apply a (deterministic) transformation to a Poisson random variable with mean $\lambda_1$ such that it remains Poisson but with mean $\lambda_2$?

One idea I had is to do the Anscombe transformation to get an approximate normally distributed random variable, and then apply a linear transformation to get the desired mean, followed by the inverse Anscombe. Of course, this is only approximate and I'm not sure if it's even valid.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not in general.

It's not possible to do it exactly if $\lambda_2>\lambda_1$, since a Poisson variable with mean $\lambda_2$ has higher entropy than one with mean $\lambda_1$, so it takes more information to specify it, even if you are willing to have a crazy non-monotone transformation.

For $\lambda_2<\lambda_1$, it is at least not always possible.  Suppose $\lambda$ is small, so that the variable basically has only values 0 and 1, and the probability of 0 is $\exp(-\lambda)$. You can't transform between two distributions like this.

I can't see any easy way to rule out that it's possible in some cases with $1 \ll \lambda_2 \ll \lambda_1$.

Comment: This makes me wonder, if you are given $\lambda_2 - \lambda_1$ (individual values are not themselves known), a black box sampler for $Poisson(\lambda_1)$ and a $U[0,1]$ sampler, can we then sample from $Poisson(\lambda_2)$.

Motivated by the case where both $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are small then in the limit to Bernoulli distributions, I think we can now perform this sampling.

Comment: Yes, absolutely. You just can't do it without a source of randomness.  For example, if $\lambda_2>\lambda_2$ you just the U[0,1] to generate Poisson($\lambda_2-\lambda_1$) and add it to what you have.

Comment: Makes sense, and if $\lambda_2 - \lambda_1 < 0$ this seems like it may need a more interesting trick as we cannot use the additive properties of independent Poisson.

Comment: I think it might now actually be impossible. In a very non-rigorous way, consider $\lambda_1 - \lambda_2 = k$ then for any sample from black box $Posisson(\lambda_1)$, there is always a possibility $\lambda_1 = k$ and hence $\lambda_2 = 0$ (in which case all samples from $Poisson(\lambda_2)$ should be 0). Therefore any method that doesn't always sample a 0 fails in this particular case but this 0 sampling method clearly fails when $\lambda_2 \neq 0$.

Comment: This answer is very interesting. Why doesn't this entropy argument work for other random variables, like a Normal?

Comment: It only works for discrete distributions. Entropy doesn't really mean the same thing for continuous distributions.  You might be able to use an information argument to show you'd be able to get more Fisher information about $\lambda_1$ by transforming before estimating, and that sort of thing does carry through (the 'data processing theorem')

Comment: @ThomasLumley, thank you for this great answer. Could you elaborate a bit more on why when $\lambda_2$ is very small, it is impossible? specifically your second paragraph. I'm don't think I completely understood your explanation

Comment: When $\lambda_1$ is small (and $\lambda_2$ is smaller) the two variables are effectively Bernoulli with different $p\approx 1-\exp(-\lambda)$.  You can't turn binary with one $p$ into binary with a different $p$ deterministically, because all the 1s have to either map to 1s or to 0s.

Answer (score 6):

If you want it to be reversible and the result to have a Poisson distribution, it's not really possible.

Poisson distributions assign probability to the non-negative integers.

1. What monotonic transformations take non-negative integers to non-negative integers?

   Unless you leave gaps in the middle of the sequence, I think all you have is shifts to the right, either of which doesn't leave you with another Poisson.

   So that rules out readily interpretable (monotonic) transformations. Assuming you want a 1-to-1 transformation (otherwise you cannot transform *back*), you're at best going to be left with "shuffling" the values in some way.

   But now note that the Poisson is unimodal (with an "edge case" of two adjacent modes when the parameter is an integer); the probabilities decrease either side of that. That severely limits your options (without even getting to the specific functional form)
2. Now consider a specific Poisson -- say a Poisson(1). It has a specific set of probabilities. Any deterministic 1-to-1 transformation will simply move those probabilities somewhere else. In general no other Poisson can share more than a fraction of those probabilities; where do the others go?  e.g. with a Poisson(1) you have two probabilities of 1/e -- you might perhaps be able to find another Poisson that has *a* probability of 1/e, but can you find one with *two* of them, both the largest possible probabilities? It turns out you can't.
3. If you *don't* require a 1-to-1 transformation, so you can steal any number of probabilities from the far tail as needed, you might in some cases be able to have a transformation from a large parameter to a good approximation of a small one, but it might be hard to give a finite-time/space *construction* of one; I think this would not be a practical exercise in general.

Comment: Not only shuffling, also summing is possible eg Poisson outcomes {1,2,3} -> 0 in different discrete distribution.

Comment: Probability integral transform and then the $Poisson(\lambda_2)$ inverse CDF, or does the discreetness wreck the probability integral transform?

Comment: @innisfree You'll note I have "1-to-1" specified there (on the assumption that a reversible transform is required). This rules out adding probabilities.

Comment: @Dave Try it :). Try to go from a Poisson(1/2) to a Poisson(5) and see what you end up with.

Comment: It seems like the discreetness prevents the probability integral transform from giving a uniform distribution. Is this what you meant? Also, how did you pick $1/2$ and $5$?

Comment: I just picked one that had some large probabilities and one that didn't have large probabilities in order for it to be obvious what the problem was.

Comment: You do: but why restrict tot hat (and reversible)? The OP doesn’t make any such restriction

Comment: You're free to explore doing so (keeping in mind the problems I mention in point 3 above); if you can offer a practical construction of such a transformation -- and a practical use for it -- I'll happily offer a bounty. Just @ me when you post, so I know to look at it.